# Does the Click-to-Run configuration.xml need "SourcePath" added to it?

Tags: xml, ms-office, office365

I am trying to install O365 on a sandbox server for our office hosted in Amazon S3.

Normally we run this on local machines and point the `SourcePath` to the fileserver and to the `Apps` folder.

This server can't reach the file server because it's hosted in very restricted environment. Can I remove the SourcePath from the XML file and replace it with something else, or can I point it back on itself to make this work?

Below is the current configuration we are using to install the Office 365 software.

```
<Configuration>
 <Add SourcePath="\\FILESERVER\Apps$" OfficeClientEdition="64">
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail" >
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
 </Add>
 <Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
 <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="1" />
 <Logging Level="Standard" Path="%temp%" />
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

If that server has Internet Access, you can remove SourcePath and the installation files will be downloaded from Office 365 Portal